# Add class to my <nav> when scroll using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, scroll

I am trying to do a simple task but I just can't see what I am doing wrong.

My goal is to add a class on my `<nav>` when the user scroll to the bottom of the page, and remove it when the he scrolls back to top.

Here's the code. PS: There's no error message on my console, and I tested if the jQuery is correctly implemented (and it is). I'm using a recent version

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop()){
      $('nav').addClass('when-scroll');
    }else {
      $('nav').removeClass('when-scroll');
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: It works when I put it into `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: That is so weird. I just put it as you suggested and it is still not working here... I am literally reading 30 times the code to understand what is wrong and just can't figure out

Comment: Also, it didn't work for me with jQuery outside the header tags for some reason

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't do that because it is for a client, but I just have a normal/functional html/css/javascript code with bootstrap as well. 1 google maps API and that is all. I tested other jQuery functions and they're working normally...

Comment: That's fine, is your jQuery included inside the header or inside body? For me it only works when defined in header tags

Comment: both my jquery inclusion and the script tag with the code are inside the body

Comment: Like I said, it worked for me only when they were in the head

Comment: oh ok, Im so tired I didnt process the information when you said it hehe. Still not working, I moved the code to the head, no error messages on my console and not working yet. That is so crazy

Comment: Sorry, can't help you. It's working for me lol    [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/5ugRRD3F) and [another](https://pastebin.com/5MsXkJ9c)

Comment: thank you so much for trying!

Comment: I've pasted two pastebins in my previous comment

Comment: I made a new html document and just copy/paste your code and it works perfectly. Now the point is to figure out WHY it is not working when it is on my code haha. Anyways, It has a google maps simple api there. Thank you bro

Answer (score 0):

you can try this;

```js
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() < scrollTop){
      $('nav').addClass('when-scroll');
    }else {
      $('nav').removeClass('when-scroll');
    }
    scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
  })
```

Comment: Hello my friend. Unfortunatelly I tried your suggestion and it is not working.

Comment: hello, is your selector correct, $('nav'). because when I tried it worked. You can put console.log's for see is it work

Comment: yeah, it selects my <nav> from the html. I also tried to select other elements to make sure, but it is like the scroll function is just not working. Any console error message is appearing.

Comment: there could be something special, do you have scroll on your page right? if your page's height not enough for scroll, scoll event won't work. I don't have other idea :(

Comment: thank you! I think it might be a positioning of my script on the html that is causing it. The page is long enough to scroll.